# Difference between js objects constructed in different ways

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between js objects created in this way? :

```
var js = {};
js.first = "blah";
js.second = something;
```

vs:

```
var js {
first : "blah",
second: something
}
```

In chrome inspector I don't see any problem. I've problem when passing js variable (first example) to socket.emit which gives me empty object in first case but works fine in the second example.

I'm confused.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828860/why-cannot-i-pass-object-via-node-js-emit

Comment: Did you miss an `=` in the second snippet?

Comment: Are you perhaps passing `js` to the socket emit before setting the `first` and `second` attributes?

Comment: @TedHopp console.dir() before in the referenced post confirms that both attributes are set before passing it to emit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between these 2 ways of creating an new object.

First example just shows how dynamically you can add new keys and values to existing object.

if you try to compare them with == you will get false, but even if you create 2 objects similar way, you will get false as well...

```
var js = {
first : "blah",
second: something
}

var js2 = {
first : "blah",
second: something
}

js == js2 //false
```

so it seems to be some browser/node bug, if it's giving you empty object. Maybe parser bug? hard to say. But there is no actual difference